# How to position text content with an h2 element to the right while still being text-aligned left?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm having an issue positioning the text content within an h2 element.
I wish to have the text content pushed to the right, but still be left-aligned. i.e. the space on the right of "SOME TEST ARTICLE HERE WITH A LONGER TITLE" to disappear by moving the text to the right.

I've tried a few different approaches, but here is my latest attempt:

[image: Screenshot of encapsulating element.]

```
<div class="article-header">
    <h2><%= article.title %></h2>
    <p><%= article.summary %></p>
</div>
```

```
.article-header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;

    h2 {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of Firefox Dev Tools.]

Appreciate the help on this, thank you.

Edit:

I'd actually also like the same effect for the p element containing the summary. I'm assuming one solution would work for both.

Comment: Try adding this to the h2 css: `width: fit-content`. Currently the h2 element is the width of its container, so it can't move.

Comment: This did not work unfortunately.

Comment: Did the `h2` change size, or is it still the same width?

Comment: The h2 size didn't change.

Comment: You need to post the HTML and CSS for the parent elements – it's that `article-header` that needs to be moved.

Comment: I could post the code of the parent element, but I don't think article-header needs to be moved. The h2 element is taking up the entire width of the article-header. I am only trying to change the positioning of the text within the h2 element.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?:

```css
.article-header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
h2 {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: flex-end;
     max-width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="article-header">
    <h2>SOME TEST ARTICLE HERE WITH A LONGER TITLE</h2>
    <p><%= article.summary %></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm going for. With the image on the left-hand side. Essentially I want the h2 text to fill up as much of the available space in the first line while sticking to the left. And then once a word cannot fit on the first line, it would go under the first word of the first line (text-aligned left).

Comment: No sorry, I meant “while sticking to the right”.

Comment: @HunterEstrada I don't understood. do you want the text to place on the image(in your first image)?

Comment: No, I don't want the text on the image. Visually I want it just as you suggested. However, I cannot insert a <br> because the title field is dynamic as it is filled in using EJS. I need a CSS solution.

Comment: @HunterEstrada I updated. please check.

Comment: Thank you, but the solution still does not work. There is space to the right of "HERE". Also, the solution needs to work with any possible text in the `h2` - this solution would only possibly work on certain titles in the `h2`.